# Is there any purpose to return the result of a function in an empty function?

Tags: javascript, web, google-tag-manager

In this example, the return of one function is passed as the return of another function. I am not sure I understand the need for that.
Example:

```
function(){
    return function(){
        // Check if the page contains the div
        var node = document.getElementById("sponsored-content"); // use whatever id your block has
        isInBody = document.body.contains(node);

        // If true
        if (isInBody){
            dataLayer.push({'event':'spContent-detected'});
        }
    }
}
```

When it could look like this:

```
 function(){
        // Check if the page contains the div
        var node = document.getElementById("sponsored-content"); // use whatever id your block has
        isInBody = document.body.contains(node);

        // If true
        if (isInBody){
            dataLayer.push({'event':'spContent-detected'});
        }
    }
```

For better context, [tag manager guide](http://marketlytics.com/tracking-banner-impressions-using-google-tag-manager-and-universal-analytics/) is the source of that original piece of code. Adding it seems to stop any other js to run if the condition is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this example, the return of one function is passed as the return of another function.

That's not what that code is doing. It's returning the *function* (itself, the actual function object), not the *result* of the function. Your outer function isn't *calling* your inner function, it's *creating and returning* it. The code in the inner function isn't executed until/unless code receiving the function reference your outer function returns calls it.

> When it could look like this

It couldn't, that does something completely different. That immediately runs the code as of when that formerly-outer function is called. But the first example isn't running that code, just creating a function that, if it gets called, will run it.

This example may help clarify it:

```js
// A function that creates functions, in this case functions that multiply
// whatever number you give them by the value used when creating the function
function makeMultiplier(mult) {
  return function(arg) {
    return arg * mult;
  };
}

// Make (but don't run!) a function that multiplies by 10
var m1 = makeMultiplier(10);

// Run it a couple of times
snippet.log(m1(5)); // 50
snippet.log(m1(7)); // 70

// Make (but don't run!) a function that multiplies by 7
var m2 = makeMultiplier(7);

// Run it a couple of times
snippet.log(m2(5)); // 35
snippet.log(m2(7)); // 49

// Run each of them again, just to show that they aren't inter-related
snippet.log(m1(6)); // 60
snippet.log(m2(6)); // 42
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```